# Finding the Basis of the Subspace U

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

U = span{[1 -1 2 5 1], [3 1 4 2 7], [1 1 0 0 0],[5 1 6 7 8]}

I tried to lay out a matrix like so

|1 -1 2 5 1|

|3 1 4 2 7|

|1 1 0 0 0|

| 5 1 6 7 8|

and solve for the rref, but apparently the vectors I get aren't the correct answer (I used Gauss Jordan Pivoting). From what I understand, these are vectors that span the rowspace of U and the non-zero rows of rref(A) should constitute a basis for this (the rowspace of A), thus the nonzero rows of rref(A) should be the answer I'm looking for.

The answer is as follows:

(1 1 0 0 0), (0 -2 2 5 1), (0 0 2 -3 6)

Which is not in row reduced echelon form, as contrary to what I was expecting.
Can someone explain the process behind getting the answer, (which I have found is similar to a version of rref where you leave the coefficients for prior variables and somehow get these vectors) ?

Comment: It might not be in _reduced_ row echelon form, but it _is_ in row echelon form. I suspect you do this in a manner completely analoguous to the rref, except you don't divide out each row to begin with a $1$. They began with the third vector in the list because it has many zeroes (easier arithmetic), and then they took the first vector because it begins with a $1$ (easier arithmetic).

Comment: Note that last vector is sum of first three, i.e, given set of vector are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, a given subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ will have an infinite number of possible bases if $n>0$, so unless you've been told to apply a particular method to a set of vectors in a particular order, there are **multiple** correct answers.

One method to find the basis for the span of set $S$ of vectors, or equivalently, a basis for the column-space of a matrix $A$ which has the vectors of $S$ as column vectors, is to reduce $A$ to RE form, then pick out the columns in $A$ corresponding to the columns in the reduced matrix with leading $1$s.  Thus:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&3&1&5\\-1&1&1&1\\2&4&0&6\\5&2&0&7\\1&7&0&8\end{bmatrix}$
Reorder to get 
$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&3&5\\1&-1&1&1\\0&2&4&6\\0&5&2&7\\0&1&7&8\end{bmatrix}$ $\rightarrow$
$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&3&5\\0&-2&-2&-4\\0&2&4&6\\0&5&2&7\\0&1&7&8\end{bmatrix}$

$\rightarrow$
$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&3&5\\0&1&1&2\\0&2&4&6\\0&5&2&7\\0&1&7&8\end{bmatrix}$
$\rightarrow$
$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&3&5\\0&1&1&2\\0&0&2&2\\0&0&-3&-3\\0&0&6&6\end{bmatrix}$
$\rightarrow$
$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&3&5\\0&1&1&2\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$, so the first $3$ vectors in $A$, transposed back, form a basis for the span, i.e. $\left\{[1,1,0,0,0], [1,-1,2,5,1], [3,1,4,2,7]\right\}$  is a basis.

Another method (which seems to be the one you use) is to write the vectors as  row vectors in a matrix and use the non-zero rows of the RE matrix as the basis:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&2&5&1\\3&1&4&2&7\\1&1&0&0&0\\5&1&6&7&8\end{bmatrix}$
$\rightarrow$
$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&2&5&1\\0&4&-2&-13&4\\0&2&-2&-5&-1\\0&6&-4&-18&3\end{bmatrix}$
$\rightarrow$
$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&2&5&1\\0&2&-2&-5&-1\\0&4&-2&-13&4\\0&6&-4&-18&3\end{bmatrix}$

$\rightarrow$
$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&2&5&1\\0&2&-2&-5&-1\\0&0&2&-3&6\\0&0&2&-3&6\end{bmatrix}$
$\rightarrow$
$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&2&5&1\\0&2&-2&-5&-1\\0&0&2&-3&6\\0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

So $\left\{[1,-1,2,5,1],[0,2,-2,-5,-1],[0,0,2,-3,6]\right\}$
is another basis.  As mentioned in Arthur's comment, we don't need to divide through to get leading $1$s (saves dealing with fractions), and don't need to continue to RRE form.

The particular set of vectors you've been given as a solution seem to have been obtained by a similar process, but with the 1st and 3rd rows swapped.